# Why does this userscript cause a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, userscripts, tampermonkey, srware-iron

My browser is SRWare Iron 24.0 Portable and Tampermonkey version is 2.12.3124.256  OR
3.0.3389.11. I write the following userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Night Mode
// @namespace   http://use.i.E.your.homepage/
// @version     1.0
// @description  Add night mode style
// @include     http*
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

function addNightStyle(){
    var rules = ['html, body { background: #383838 !important; }',
        'div { background-color: #383838 !important; }',
        'header,nav,table,th,tr,td,dl,ul,li,ol,fieldset,form,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre { background: transparent !important;}',
        '* { color: #B6AA7B !important; }',
        'a:link,a:link *,a:link:hover,a:link:hover *,a:link:active,a:link:active * { color: #B6AA7B !important; }',
        'a:visited,a:visited *,a:visited:hover,a:visited:hover *,a:visited:active,a:visited:active * { color: #D9C077 !important; }'
        ];
    with( document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style')) ){
        id = 'nightmode';
        for(var i=0; i<rules.length; i++){
            sheet.insertRule(rules[i], i);
        }
    }
}
setTimeout(addNightStyle,90);
```

When this script is active, memory usage and virtual size of the renderer process increase gradually as I browse through more pages. Memory can only be released by closing all the tabs of the corresponding renderer process.

Why does this script cause a memory leak?

How to fix it?

Comment: What should `sheet` be?

Comment: CSSStyleSheet of the <style> element.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet

Comment: Don't do it this way!  For just style changes, use Stylish. Otherwise, use `GM_addStyle()`.  Does the memory leak when the script is just a one-line, console.log()? Try clearing that setTimeout when done, but you shouldn't use a timer in this case anyway; test DOM state or don't run at start.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `rules` is a keyword in this case, your loop doesn't even start, you have to choose a different name for your rule list. Anyway, according to [MDN Reference - CSSStyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet#Properties), you cannot access `insertRule` this way, but you can do this instead:

```
function addNightStyle(){
    var ruleList = ['html, body { background: #383838 !important; }',
        'div { background-color: #383838 !important; }',
        'header,nav,table,th,tr,td,dl,ul,li,ol,fieldset,form,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre { background: transparent !important;}',
        '* { color: #B6AA7B !important; }',
        'a:link,a:link *,a:link:hover,a:link:hover *,a:link:active,a:link:active * { color: #B6AA7B !important; }',
        'a:visited,a:visited *,a:visited:hover,a:visited:hover *,a:visited:active,a:visited:active * { color: #D9C077 !important; }'
        ];
    document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style'));
    with(sheet = document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1]){
        id = 'nightmode';
        for (var i = 0; i < ruleList.length; i++) {
            sheet.insertRule(ruleList[i], i);
        }
    }
}
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cJ8wx/1/)

Comment: Tested. Still memory leak. The stylesheet object access through document.styleSheets or by the sheet property of style element is strictly equal (===). So I think this is not the cause of memory leak.
---
Also, if there is a style element in the body, the last style sheet is not the one appended to the head. (I know this is not standard, but some page do this.)

Comment: Yep you're right, I didn't noticed that. Anyway, I don't really understand why it doesn't work, in the fiddle it doesn't give me any issue...